# How to locate multiple chosen files in new inputs with type="file"?

Tags: javascript

How to locate multiple chosen files in new inputs with type="file"?

**General input:**

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="images"multiple="multiple">
```

**Inputs created by js for dispense:**

```
 <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple="multiple">
 <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple="multiple">
 <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: Hi @Karen, please, read this before ask a question: [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please, provide more info... Can you provide an example of what you want?, Can you specify what language do you want to use (only javascript, jquery... etc)? What is the diference between first and second code?

Comment: How to locate multiple chosen files in new inputs with type="file"?

Comment: explain your problem more please

Comment: Other time... please, read this before ask a question: [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Karen Simply repeating the questions title does not clarify anything.  We can already see the title.

Answer (score 0):

that how I would approach this:

```
// This is not ES6, but the idea is the same
var selectedFiles = [];

// Get all input[file] fields

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='file']");

// Loop trough every match

for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    console.log(inputs[i]);
  // Check if this input have any selected files
  if (inputs[i].files.length > 0) {

    // loop to check every file
    for (var i = 0; i <= inputs.files.length - 1; i++) {

      var fname = inputs.files.item(i).name;      // THE NAME OF THE FILE.
      var fsize = inputs.files.item(i).size;      // THE SIZE OF THE FILE.
      selectedFiles.push([fname,fsize]);
    }
  }
  // Show the contents
  console.log("Files: ", selectedFiles);
}
```

Hope it helps :)